# Text Disappears After Being Changed in Animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to build a Quiz iOS App and when the user finishes the question it slides away and is replaced by a new question. However when I replace the text with a new question it disappears (Ex. Animation finishes and works perfectly then directly after that text disappears).

```
 func slideOutThenIn() {
    viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self.viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.view.frame.width, y: 0)
        self.viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.view.frame.width, y: 0)

    }) { (_) in

        self.viewUpperContainer.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        self.viewLowerContainer.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: (-self.view.frame.width * 2), y: 0)
            self.viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: (-self.view.frame.width * 2), y: 0)

        }, completion: {finished in
            self.questionLabel.text = self.allQuestions.list[self.questionNumber].questionText
        })
    }

}
```

I would like the text to change during the animation but for now I'm happy with it changing right after the animation has completed without it disappearing.

Comment: As I can see you are moving your views out of screen.

Comment: Yes, the way the code is supposed to work is the animation slides the text out of the screen then the text is changed and then slid back into the screen.

Comment: You view should be in 0 to screen's width. Let is suppose as 0 & 1. You are moving it to -1 then +2. Ultimately your views are out of screen. Total translation should be 0 if you want out-in animation. But here you have +1 translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer that worked for me.

```
func slideOutThenIn() {
    viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
    viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

        self.viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.view.frame.width, y: 0)
        self.viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -self.view.frame.width, y: 0)

    }) { (_) in

        self.viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.width, y: 0)
        self.viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: self.view.frame.width, y: 0)

        self.questionLabel.text = self.allQuestions.list[self.questionNumber].questionText

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

            self.viewUpperContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
            self.viewLowerContainer.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)

        }, completion: {finished in
        })
    }

}
```